# Signing domain with existing Google ID up for Google Apps

Tags: google-apps

Is it possible to sign up a domain for Google Apps, if a Google ID has already been created under that domain, without destroying the existing Google ID?

Example: user@example.com is a Google ID, used for Analytics and Adwords. If example.com is now signed up for Google Apps, what will happen to the user@example.com user ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing will happen with the data of your "old" google Id.
The first time you will log in to a service with your google apps id google will ask a question if you want to migrate your data into the google apps account or into another google account.

With kind regards,

Thomas van Latum

Comment: Had a few things to fall in place first, but it worked out just like you said. Thanks.